# XAML horizontal alignment

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, alignment

I have a question on Windows Phone 7 XAML programming.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="110">
    <Canvas Margin="0">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Menesis}" Foreground="{Binding MyColor}"></TextBlock>
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas Margin="0,12,0,0">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Datums}" Foreground="{Binding MyColor}" FontSize="85" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"  />
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas Margin="0,105,0,0">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nedelas_diena}" Foreground="{Binding MyColor}" />
    </Canvas>
</StackPanel>
```

How to make `TextBlock` (Binding Datums) text centered? Currently it is aligned at right side and

```
 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
```

or

```
TextAlignment="Center"
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you wrapping your TextBlocks in Canvases?  A Canvas is only good for positioning a control at a specific X,Y coordinate with a specific width and height.  Controls like Grids and StackPanels are designed to control the layout and sizing of other controls according to the available area...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have your TextBlock in a Canvas you will have problems with the alignment as the TextBlack will be placed at 0,0 (top left) inside the canvas control and (unless you set the width explicitly) will be stretched to fit the text contained. This basically means your text will always be left aligned.

The Canvas control should only be used when you need to set the exact position of the contained elements. If this is not the case then use another container such as a Grid, StackPanel or even just a ContentControl.

Remove the Canvas from your xaml and it should work.

To clarify HorizontalAlignment vs. TextAlignment:
If you have a ContentControl that is 400px wide and you add a TextBlock to it that is set to be 200px wide with text content that is 100px wide, then the following is true:

- Setting the HorizontalAlignment to Center will align the TextBlock (200px wide) to the middle of the ContentControl but the text will still be left aligned within the TextBlock. This means the text will be offset 100px from the left.
- If just the TextAlignment is set to Center then the TextBlock will be left-aligned but the text inside will be centered. This means that the text will be offset 50px from the left.

In my opinion the best practise here is not to set any widths and just set the TextAlignment property. This will mean (for most containers) the TextBlock will be stretched the entire width of the container and the text within aligned appropriately.

Comment: It worked perfectly with grid! Code also became more readable

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using stack panel and canvas . either u can use Grid. If you are using grid you can point out the exact position where you need to place the control.
for eg,

<----- Height -->

like this. More over there is no need to use canvas. The canvas container is using mainly in case of game design purpose.